# How can I run Minecraft Forge Run using Java 7 without uninstalling Java 8?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-forge

I have JRE 8 installed on my pc as I code a lot of small stuff in Java.

But apparently you need JRE 7 to run minecraft forge. As I am not confortable with uninstalling JRE 8 just so that I can play minecraft with mods, is there any way to make the minecraft launcher use JRE 7 while everything else uses JRE 8?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, I found the solution to this. I just installed JRE 7 and edited the launcher profile with the executable as "C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe" this allows me to use JRE 8 normally but JRE 7 in minecraft and it runs perfectly now.